# Is there such thing as a guitar string database?

Tags: guitar, strings

I'm completely new to guitars and guitar accessories.

I read several articles on (everything, but this question pertains to) strings, and it strikes me that one might want to try a set of strings with certain characteristics.  Initially I figured this wouldn't be too much of a struggle, but in my quest to find a set of light/extra light (10s) acoustic flatwound coated strings, I've been unsuccessful.

This has been made more difficult by the lack of useful filtering functionality on websites that sell strings, so even though store A might have 3800 different sets of strings, there's not a good way to find what you want even if it exists.

It seems like the done thing might instead be to choose strings based on only one characteristic, and then stick with a specific brand or what have you.

Originally this question was specifically "where can I find acoustic flatwound coated 10s?"  But I figure a more useful and broad question is the one asked in the title.  With a comprehensive database of string brand-model combinations, and all their characteristics, one could easily look for what they want, then search for e.g. "D'Addario EFT15" and not have to deal with the issues I encountered.

Comment: "!s there such thing as a guitar string database? "If so, then regardless of any inadequate filtering functionality you found on websites that sell strings, I think it would show up in an internet search. 
https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=guitar+string+database

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't clear in my comment on your previous answer - the link to a search website is the part that isn't useful.  It's expected that an asker has already searched before posting a question.  If you are able to find what they're looking for with a search then that finding is an answer, but the search site is not.  (The search _terms_ might be).  What I meant for you to comment was the frame challenge of "wanting strings with specific characteristics is not done". If you could explain how I could improve my question such that you'll remove your downvote, that will be appreciated.

Comment: Adam the frame challenge was incidental, as part of my desire to provide you with an actual answer that contained something to try and help, rather than flatly commenting "This is not a good question". I'm afraid I can't suggest any way to redeem a question titled "!s there such thing as a guitar string database?", since imo that will always be a question for an internet search rather than SE. Maybe if you go back to your original idea rather than trying to make it generic, that will help? But simply changing the title wouldn't do it; the question needs to focus on one thing really.

Comment: Have you tried JustStrings.com?  it's not a database but the website appears to be very easy to navigate to narrow down the string selection to what you are looking for.

Comment: I have seen and used flat wound strings and often use coated acoustic strings. But I have never seen flat wound coated strings for an acoustic or even electric guitar.  I can't see a benefit to coating a flat wound guitar string which already as some of the characteristics I like about coated round wound strings.  I think fretless bass strings might come in coated flat wound because with no frets, the strings can damage the fingerboard.

Comment: What benefits or characteristics are you hoping to find with coated flat wound strings that existing types of strings don't offer?

Comment: As it stands this is a resource request. If I can't find a product that I want, I generally turn to a trusted retailer. In the US, it's hard to find better than Sweetwater at Sweetwater.com, but your local music store, Guitar Center, Sam Ash, or Music & Arts location hopefully has at least one person who knows how to go through their supplier's catalogs and find the closest thing possible to what you seek. You can also join Facebook groups and other online communities to ask where to find things. You can't ask here in a question, but you could in the chat!

Comment: @RegEdit Questions that can be answered by a web search are not ipso facto unwelcome on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I'm not sure everyone would agree with that assertion. Could you explicate, and hopefully link to any discussions on this so I may consider it further?

Comment: @RegEdit If you haven't been through Meta.SE you're missing a lot about how SE works. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/09/15/stack-overflow-launches/

Comment: @RockinCowboy - Just Strings  did me very well a few yrs ago. I was looking for a tapewound, double ball low B for a headless fretless bass. At the time, the only helpful and stocked place was - Just Strings.

Comment: @RockinCowboy perhaps worth it's own question, but my understanding is the main benefit of flat wound strings is less fret wear, and of coated strings is higher longevity.  As a side effect, both also change the sound of the strings.

Comment: "Questions seeking recommendations for specific equipment are off-topic" this specifically isn't seeking a recommendation for specific piece of equipment.  It's a request for a resource to find one's own equipment.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard of comprehensive database. This becomes in particular an issue when searching for strings for extended length guitar. Is the string is long enough to reach the farthest peg on a 6-in-line headstock? Does the double-taper end behind the nut, but before the pegs? Many string producers don't even publish information like that and you need to ask them individually.

Search *various* online music stores. Many of them make effort to categorize string sets according to string gauge and other parameters. Better check more than one store, as each of the search engines have some flaws, and they are limited to brands sold in that store.

Comment: Another excellent reason one might want such a database, thank you.

Comment: Agreed! I've been looking for a new string set for my 6 string baritone guitar and this information (string length) is rarely present in the description. Also, it would be lovely to be able to search all string packs in existence by their gauges and stuff.